# Sound is gone after booting system in text mode

Tags: grub2, sound, console, xserver

I started using 
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text"` grub argument for my boots, and recently noticed that the sound is missing. I start GUI from terminal using `startx` command,

here's my **.xinitrc** file:

```
#!/bin/bash

awesome
```

`alsamixer` command gives this output:

```
`cannot open mixer: No such file or directory`
```

Comment: A bug may be? https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1004156

Comment: @Ron I'm under impression that it's simply not being started while entering text mode, guess i have to start it during gui boot somehow....

Comment: Tried  `pulseaudio --start`  ?

Comment: @Serg yes I did